# dbReadTable won't pull data but dbListFields will see correct fields

Tags: sql, r, r-dbi

I am trying to pull data from a SQL database that I have access to.  I can connect to the database, see the tables and get the fields associated with a given table, but cannot read a table into an R variable.

I'm working in R Studio, in case this makes a difference.

I have tried using online code snippets (new to R) and these work, except for the dbReadTable() examples.  I have used both "Payments" and name="Payments" as the second argument, and both with and without "" quotes.

```r
library(DBI)
con<-(dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string="Driver={SQL Server},
Server=example_1234
Database=exampleDB
TrustedConnection=TRUE")

testing123 <- dbListFields(con,"Payments")
testing456 <- dbReadTable(con,"Payments")
```

I expect a connection to the database which is now named con.  This works.
I expect testing123 to contain all the fields in "Payments". This also works.
I expect testing456 to be a data.frame copy of Payments. This produces:
Error: 'SELECT * FROM "Payments"
nanodbc/nanobdc.cpp:1587 42s02 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL SERVER DRIVER][SQL SERVER]Invalid pbject name 'Payments'.

It's slightly different without "Payments" as the argument - simply saying "Object "Payments" not found".

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it's because your table is in a different catalog or schema.

**Rationale**: `DBI::dbListFields` is doing `select * from ... limit 0` (which is not correct syntax for sql server), but `odbc::dbListFields` is really calling a C++ function `connection_sql_columns` that is SQL Server specific. It might be permitting you to be a touch sloppy in that it will find the table even if you do not specify the catalog and/or schema. This is why your `dbListFields` is working. *However*, `DBI::dbReadTable` is really doing `select * from ...` under the hood (and `odbc::` is not overriding it), so it is not allowing you to omit the schema (and/or catalog).

First, find the specific table information for your case:

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select top 1 table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='events'")
#   table_catalog table_schema table_name column_name
# 1    my_catalog          dbo   Payments          Id
```

(I'm projecting what you'll find.)

From here, try one of the following until it works:

```r
x <- DBI::dbReadTable(con, DBI::SQL("[Payments]")) # equivalent to the original
x <- DBI::dbReadTable(con, DBI::SQL("[dbo].[Payments]"))
x <- DBI::dbReadTable(con, DBI::SQL("[my_catalog].[dbo].[Payments]"))
```

My guess is that `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select top 1 * from Payments")` will not work, so for "regular queries" you'll need to use the same hierarchy of `catalog.schema.table`, such as one of

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select top 1 * from dbo.Payments")
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select top 1 * from [dbo].[Payments]")
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select top 1 * from [my_catalog].[dbo].[Payments]")
```

(The use of the `[` and `]` quoted-identifier brackets are often a personal preference, strictly required in only some corner cases.)

Comment: Excellent, works and I have more understanding of what was going on too!  Thanking you!

Had no idea that the dbListFields was running something other than a SQL Query, hence being baffled why one was fine and the other wasn't.

Comment: I am able to leverage this with "select top X * from my_schema.my_table"; but if I eliminate the "top X" portion, I get an error. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your con argument just slightly:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
    Server = "example_1234",
    Database = "exampleDB",
    TrustedConnection = TRUE)

# read table to df
testing456 <- dbReadTable(con,"Payments")

# you can also use SQL queries directly, such as:
testing789 <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = "SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE ...")
```

Comment: The `odbc` package is not redefining `dbReadTable`, so it is using `DBI::dbReadTable` which is [doing exactly this](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blob/6f34ab4c4cfff82d2d5ddd4ce1f9ed5e53e8ed88/R/DBConnection.R#L558).